# Laravel resource controller show() return image stream

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I want to return an image stream from a Laravel resource controller `show()` method, is that possible?

I'm attempting to use the aws-sdk S3 stream wrapper, which provides image data via streams as to avoid loading an entire image into memory, and return that from the `show()` method.

Docs for the AWS S3 stream wrapper for PHP: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-stream-wrapper.html

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `streamDownload` return.

You will have to fill in the function with the required code to open and echo the remote data. Replace the content type header and filename as required.

```
       return response()->streamDownload(function() {
            // stream contents here
            // s3 fetch, echo file contents from remote url, etc.
        }, "super-duper.png", ['content-type' => 'image/png']);
```